# How exactly do I add external libraries to my JavaFX Gradle Project?

Tags: java, javafx, import

I use IntelliJ IDEA and I'm on Java 19.
I have a JavaFX project and I need to import 3D models into it. I've found this library com.almasb.fx3d.modelloading to do it.  I downloaded it from github and extracted it.
Here's the link to it.
https://github.com/AlmasB/javafx3d-samples
Now on IntelliJ, to add the library, I go to project structure -> Libraries -> + and I add the lib file of the library there. Then I do the same for the Modules -> Dependencies -> Add JAR or directory.
Now I try to import the external library but IntelliJ just refuses to detect that I've added the library.
I use

```
import com.almasb.fx3d.modelloading;
```

But I get the error

> "cannot resolve symbol".

I also tried creating a lib file in my project folder, adding the JAR file there and making it a dependency, but still no luck.
I just joined the website, so if I need to add more information or some sort of pictures, please let me know.

Now I try to import the external library but IntelliJ just refuses to detect that I've added the library.
I use
import com.almasb.fx3d.modelloading;
But I get the error "cannot resolve symbol".

I also tried creating a lib file in my project folder, adding the JAR file there and making it a dependency, but still no luck.
I just joined stackexchange, so if I need to add more information or some sort of pictures, please let me know.
I also tried doing this with another library called JavaFX Fxyz. It didn't have a lib folder so I literally referenced each folder in the library separately to see if that would fix the issue, but it didn't.

Edit: Added a screenshot showing the libraries and the modules. I've tried adding both the .jar file, as well as the folder it's stored in.

[image: Libraries Screenshot]

[image: Modules Screenshot]

For the minimal reproducible example, since I'm on JavaFX, I've used a simple Hello World application.

```
package com.example.test_project;

import com.almasb.fx3d.*; // Doesn't detect the library added
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        ObjModelImporter omi = new ObjectModelImporter(); // error as import doesn't work
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 320, 240);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Controller

```
package com.example.test_project;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class HelloController {
    @FXML
    private Label welcomeText;

    @FXML
    protected void onHelloButtonClick() {
        welcomeText.setText("Welcome to JavaFX Application!");
    }
}
```

FXML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="com.example.test_project.HelloController">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0"/>
    </padding>

    <Label fx:id="welcomeText"/>
    <Button text="Hello!" onAction="#onHelloButtonClick"/>
</VBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Let Gradle manage your libraries

Do not download and install libraries manually.

One of the main purposes of Gradle is to serve as a “dependency manager”. “Dependency” is a fancy word for “a library you want to use in your app”. Gradle can automatically locate your desired library in a “repository”, download the library, and install the library to make it available in your IDE’s project.

Using a dependency manager for all your libraries can avoid falling into [dependency hell](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell).

All modern IDEs, including IntelliJ, know how to work with Gradle. Notice in your screenshot how a bunch of the listed libraries are prefixed by `Gradle:` indicating they were sourced by Gradle.  Delete the items there that you manually added, the ones lacking that “Gradle” prefix.

All you have to do is:

- Specify a [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) repository where your library is kept. The default repository already configured in your Gradle settings will likely suffice.
- Add a dependency entry in your Gradle configuration file to specify the name and version of your desired library.

[Read Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle) to learn the basics of Gradle. Then do a web search to learn [how to add a dependency in Gradle](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=add%20dependency%20in%20gradle&t=ipad&ia=qa).

You may be annoyed at having to learn another tool. But really truly, investing a bit of time into learning how to use Gradle and/or Maven to drive your builds, including dependency management, is well worth it.

Comment: @trashgod Actually, now that I looked at the OP's link, it appears to be *not* a library but a bunch of example code.

Comment: My error: at least one dependency from [here](http://interactivemesh.org/models/jfx3dimporter.html) is [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/us.ihmc/jim3dsModelImporterJFX/0.7).